# Minimising surface with given curve as a boundary

Tags: differential-geometry, minimal-surfaces

I have a problem connected to finding a minimal surface with a given boundary. I know that it is the surface with zero mean curvature but as I have to obain differential equations for such surface I decided to do it by looking for extremal points of area functional:

$$
S= \int\limits_{surface} \sqrt{\text{det}(g_{ind})}
$$
where $g_{ind}$ is the metric induced on my 2d surface from (in my case) rather nontrivial 4 dimensional metric (Einstein summation convention from now on):

$$
g_{ind, \mu \nu}=g_{\alpha, \beta}\frac{\partial X^\alpha}{\partial \sigma_\mu}\frac{\partial X^\beta}{\partial \sigma_\nu}
$$
Where $\sigma^\nu, \nu\in {1,2}$ are the coordinates on surface.
to the functional $S$ I applied standard Euler-Lagrange equations. But then I thought that the standard trick when looking for minimal curves: rather then minimise the length functional:
$$
\int\limits_{curve} \sqrt{g_{\mu \nu}\frac{d X^\mu}{d t}\frac{d X^\nu}{d t}}
$$

one can minimise

$$
\int\limits_{curve} g_{\mu \nu}\frac{d X^\mu}{d t}\frac{d X^\nu}{d t}
$$
and obtain identical set of equations. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodesic#Riemannian_geometry) states that minimising those two is equavalent due to Swartz inequality. So I tried the trick with my S functional and minimise such integral

$$
\tilde{S}= \int\limits_{surface} \text{det}(g_{ind})
$$

instead, but it turned out that the set of equations now obtained is not equivalent to those obtained by ninimising $S$. Can anyone explain to me why this does not work? does it mean that I have made some errors in my calculation? Or just the 2d case does not allow this simplification?

Comment: The first approach wasn't leading anywhere: there is no sensible Euler-Lagrange equation for area functional (just as there isn't one for length functional). For curve, one minimizes the integral of squared velocity, i.e., "energy". Similarly in 2D: the Dirichlet energy (of conformal parametrization) is the functional to be minimized. Why are you trying to develop the theory from scratch? There are books written about minimal surfaces.